# Do Ganapatis accept other scriptures?

Tags: ganesha

so Ganapatis have their own Upanishad.I presume they also accept the vedas.do they accept all the authentic upanishads?what about itihasa?

Comment: Are you talking about *ghanapAThis*? If so, they accept the major upanishads.

Answer (score 2):

GAanapatyas are exclusive worshippers of Ganesha. Ganesha is the Lord of the Ganas and he is the first worshipped before undertaking any auspicious activity and before performing the puja of any other god or deity. The scriptures related to Ganesha are, The Mudgal Puran which describes the eight incarnations of Ganesha, The Ganesh Purana , several slokas, Stotras sung in praise of Ganesha. Information on Ganesha is liberally found in several upa Puranas. The Atharvasheershanopanishad by Ganaka Rishi is entirely dedicated to Ganesha and it is chanted in every Ganesha puja. Gaanapatyas worship Ganapati as Brahmanaspati, the Adhipati of all Brahmas, hence Brahmanaspati.